# one :before psuedo element before four h1..?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

For the life of me cannot get his to work - I'm try to insert one icon font before a group of h1 tags within a div. I can get one icon font before each H1 tag, but this is not what I want. To re-iterate, one icon font before the div, not each h1. Any help would be massively appreciated. FYI - the text within the H1 consists animate.css fade in and delay, hence the seperate IDs and tags.

```css
.container{
  position:;
  margin:0px auto;
  background-color:pink;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.motto-text {
  position:absolute;
  display: ;
  bottom:;
  left:;
}

#hero-text .motto-text:before {
  font-family: icomoon;
  content: "\e600"; 
  display:block;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  padding-right:3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}​
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="hero-text" class="motto-text"><!-- Hero text to start-->
    <h1 id="delayedText1" class="animated fadeIn delay-1">Line 1</h1>
    <h1 id="delayedText2" class="animated fadeIn delay-2">Line 2</h1>
    <h1 id="delayedText3" class="animated fadeIn delay-3">Line 3</h1>
    <h1 id="delayedText4" class="animated fadeIn delay-4">Line</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong selector: `#hero-text .motto-text:before` does not match any element in your markup, since it is a child selector. Use `#hero-text.motto-text:before` or just `#hero-text:before` instead.

Comment: That doesn't work either - I take it you meant removing the space between the classes, as your selectors are the same..?

Comment: The selectors are not the same. The space in the code makes the selector a child selector. So it is necessary to remove it. If this does not fix the problem, then you have *another* error, which cannot be seen from the code posted. It can be your icon font; your code does actually define it at all. Test first with the `content` attribute containing normal characters to see that it is indeed displayed.

Comment: Icon font is definitely working - I can display this above the #hero-text but not before.  I can also add h1 to the selector and it will add the icon font before each h1 selector. I just can't get it to display infront of the #hero-text div

Comment: The code in the question works, after the fix in my answer and provided that the icon font works. If things don’t work for you, you have some other code that causes the problem, hence another problem, which you might post as a new question, with sufficient code to actually reproduce it. You can see this if you test this code as such. I have also described how to see the effect better; you might also consider setting the color to red instead of white, for testing.

Comment: The new question was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144141/before-psuedo-element-not-working-on-h1-tag